# Decoupling a class which is used by the lots of subclasses

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Hi I have a situation like that;

[image]

I have different items in my design and all these items has some specific effect on the Character. There is an apply function in every item so it can use Character object and change its functionalities. But what if I change the Character function, I would have to change all the Item classes in accordance to that.

How can I decouple Item and Character efficiently?

The language I am going to use is C++ and I don't know the other variables and functions inside the Item and Character classes. I just want to decouple them.

Comment: In an OOP design, `Character` would apply changes to itself. Separating the logic into `Item` and the data into `Character` is _procedural programming_ rather than OOP.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce an interface (abstract class in C++) that `Character` would inherit. Let's call it `ItemUser`. The `Item#apply` signature would be changed so that it would take an object of `ItemUser` instead of `Character`. Now you are able to change the implementation of `Character` freely as long as it respects the `ItemUser` contract.

Answer (score 0):

Check Decorator design pattern, it seems that this design pattern is what you are looking for. Link :[Decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

As per what I have understood from reading your question is : You have multiple Item classes each having a effect associated. Effect corressponding to the type of Item object is applied on another entity which is Character. Now your issue is whenever there is a change in Character class your Item classes also needs to change and you want a cleaner way to avoid this.

A good way to handle change is to define the well defined Contract which is less prone to change. For example if we have a functionality to add two integers and later we may have the changes such that we require to add two floating point numbers and later we may need to replace add operation with multiplication. In such a case you can define an abstraction Compute (INum num1, INum num2) : INum as return type. Here INum is an abstraction for type and Compute is abstraction for behaviour of function. Actual implementation defines INum and Compute. Now code using our code only depends on the abstractions and we can freely modify the operation and actual type without affecting the user code.

While implementing the contract you can modify the internal implementation without affecting the outside code using the contract.

You can define an abstract class ICharacter. For certain attributes whose type can change in future you can use Templates and generics or simply create interface for the attribute type as well and let the concrete type implement the interfaces. Refer all your fields with interfaces.  Let ICharacter define public abstract methods with parameters of type Interfaces and return type also as Interfaces.

Let Item class use ICharacter and When you need to apply effect as per item class just use the constant abstract functions defined. Your Character internal modifications now can change without affecting the Item class.